# Changing the text of the "static text" control and its color at once (a bad behavior occurred)

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to change the text of the "static text" control and its color at once,  and I have done that, but the problem is when changing the text first and then changing the color of that text, it takes a little noticeable time between changing the text and its color.

[image]

```
bool IsGameOpen = false;
INT_PTR CALLBACK DialogProc(HWND hDlg, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (uMsg) {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
    {
        SetTimer(hDlg, GAME_STATUS_TIMER, 1000, NULL);
        return TRUE;
    }
    case WM_TIMER:
        switch (wParam) {
        case GAME_STATUS_TIMER:
            if (Mem->FindProcess()) {
                SetDlgItemTextW(hDlg, GAME_CURRENT_STATUS_LBL, L"Open");
                IsGameOpen = true;

            } else {
                SetDlgItemTextW(hDlg, GAME_CURRENT_STATUS_LBL, L"Closed");
                IsGameOpen = false;
            }
            break;
        }
        return TRUE;
    case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
    {
        if ((HWND)lParam == GetDlgItem(hDlg, GAME_CURRENT_STATUS_LBL)) {
            if (IsGameOpen) {
                SetTextColor((HDC)wParam, RGB(29, 122, 9));
                return (BOOL)GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_MENU);
            } else {
                SetTextColor((HDC)wParam, RGB(176, 12, 12));
                return (BOOL)GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_MENU);
            }
        }
        break;
    }
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

**What's wrong with my code that makes the program take a little noticeable time between changing the text and its color?**

Comment: The GUi needs to be built. That takes a little time. You may be compiling your code without optimizations enabled (which makes it really slow).

Comment: @JesperJuhl: I have compiled the program with `Maximum Optimization (Favor Speed) (/O2)` but that behavior still occurs.

Comment: Set the variable first, and then set the text?

Comment: Notice that your code doesn't *set* the colour - the text control asks it for the colour, *when it paints.* So it's probably painting during SetDlgItemTextW (with the old colour because the variable IsGameOpen isn't updated) and then painting again some time later (for some unrelated reason) with the next colour (because it was updated)

Comment: @user253751: You're right, when setting the `IsGameOpen`  first before changing text everything became normal. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in comments, the Static control is likely being repainted immediately, and thus sending `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` to you, while `SetDlgItemTextW()` is being processed, but you haven't updated your `IsGameOpen` variable yet, so the new color doesn't take effect until the *next* time the Static control has to be repainted.

Try this instead:

```
case GAME_STATUS_TIMER:
    IsGameOpen = Mem->FindProcess();
    SetDlgItemTextW(hDlg, GAME_CURRENT_STATUS_LBL, IsGameOpen ? L"Open" : L"Closed");
    break;
```